# Generate Random Integers

Tags: vb.net, math, random, numbers, integer

I like to generate a List(of Integer), and I am trying to check that no randomnumber will occur twice:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateRandomUniqueNumbers(ByVal Amount As Integer)
As List(Of Integer)
    Dim rnd As New System.Random
    Dim CreatedRandoms As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Amount
        Dim Current As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 999999999)
        If Not CreatedRandoms.Contains(Current) Then
            CreatedRandoms.Add(Current)
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
    Return CreatedRandoms
End Function
```

But when I pass 10 as amount its only outputing 6 (the list only contain 6 items... ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot increase counter in case variable is present in a list:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Amount
    Dim Current As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 999999999)
    If Not CreatedRandoms.Contains(Current) Then
        CreatedRandoms.Add(Current)
    End If
    i += 1
    ^^^^^^^
Next
```

change this to:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateRandomUniqueNumbers(ByVal Amount As Integer)
As List(Of Integer)
    Dim rnd As New System.Random
    Dim CreatedRandoms As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Amount
        Dim Current As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 999999999)
        If Not CreatedRandoms.Contains(Current) Then
            CreatedRandoms.Add(Current)
            i += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return CreatedRandoms
End Function
```

You should add also break condition in case another random number cannot be generated. This is quite unlikely but much easier to imagine if your Amount gets bigger and/or random numbers generator has smaller period. So maybe something like this:

```
Dim repetition As Integer = 0;

   For i As Integer = 0 To Amount

        /* Has max limit of repetitions been reached so far? */
        If repetition > MAX_REPETITIONS Then exit_report_error()

        /* generate new value */
        Dim Current As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 999999999)

        If Not CreatedRandoms.Contains(Current) Then
            CreatedRandoms.Add(Current)
            i += 1
            repetition = 0   // reset counter
        Else
            repetition += 1  // accumulate repetitions
   Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it's generating repeat values.

You could do this instead, though obviously you don't get a guarantee for how long it could potentially run:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateRandomUniqueNumbers(ByVal Amount As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim rnd As New System.Random
    Dim CreatedRandoms As New List(Of Integer)
    Do While CreatedRandoms.Count() < Amount
        Dim Current As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 999999999)
        If Not CreatedRandoms.Contains(Current) Then
            CreatedRandoms.Add(Current)
        End If
    Loop
    Return CreatedRandoms
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the error, had to remove the i+=1

That was manually incrementing a counter that was already incrementing automatically.